# Use OpenMP in C++11 to find the maximum of the calculated values

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

I am looking to find the maximum of the calculated values inside of a for loop and also store its corresponding index, ***max_calc_value*** and ***i_max*** here, below is my pseudo code. I was wondering if it is possible to do a certain kind of reduction here:

```
double max_calc_value = -DBL_MAX; // minimum double value
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 20; i < 1000; i++) {
    this_value = my_slow_function(large_double_vector_array, param1*i, .., param5+i);
    if (this_value > max_calc_value){
        max_calc_value = this_value;
        i_max = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure that the max-value check is inside an atomic section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to handle it is to define a custom reduction operation as shown in Gilles' answer. If your compiler only supports OpenMP 3.1 or earlier (custom reduction operations were introduced in OpenMP 4.0), then the proper solution is to perform local reduction in each thread and then sequentially combine the local reductions:

```
double max_calc_value = -DBL_MAX; // minimum double value
int i_max = -1;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int my_i_max = -1;
    double my_value = -DBL_MAX;

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 20; i < 1000; i++) {
        this_value = my_slow_function(large_double_vector_array, param1*i, .., param5+i);
        if (this_value > my_value){
            my_value = this_value;
            my_i_max = i;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        if (my_value > max_calc_value) {
            max_calc_value = my_value;
            i_max = my_i_max;
        }
    }
}
```

This minimises the synchronisation overhead from the `critical` construct and in a simplified way shows how the `reduction` clause is actually implemented.

Comment: I agree with Hristo on his recommendation for OpenMP 3.  Even with a well implemented OpenMP 4, the nested reduction is useful in my experience, with omp parallel for reduction firstprivate lastprivate in the outer loop and omp simd reduction lastprivate in the inner loop (although Hristo's old style seems best for Intel(r) Xeon Phi(tm) and seems to be used by some experts on the newer KNL)

Comment: Thanks very much!!

Comment: Hristo, I have a quick follow up questions: in your sample code here, is my large vector array, large_double_vector_array, being passed by reference or value to the various parallel threads?

Comment: Variables defined outside the parallel region are shared by default. The threads are receiving a reference of some kind of the original variable, either as a pointer in a special data structure passed to the thread (for OpenMP implementations that use code outlining == most compilers) or the compiler directly uses the original variable in thread's code.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. So I don't have to worry about my large vector array's copies being made for each thread.

Comment: Wait...I mean `nowait`.

Answer (score 7):

If you feel like it, you can define a custom reduction function and use it in parallel. In your specific example, that might just make the code a bit more cumbersome than simply using a `critical` section. However, this might apply nicely if your actual code can globally benefit from using this custom reduction function, not only for the final parallel reduction, but also for the local ones...
So in case it applies to you, here is an example on how it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

struct dbl_int {
    double val;
    int idx;
};

const dbl_int& max( const dbl_int& a, const dbl_int& b) {
    return a.val > b.val ? a : b;
}

#pragma omp declare reduction( maxVal: dbl_int: omp_out=max( omp_out, omp_in ) )

int main() {
    dbl_int di = { -100., -1 };
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads( 10 ) reduction( maxVal: di )
    {
        di.val = omp_get_thread_num() % 7;
        di.idx = omp_get_thread_num();
    }
    std::cout << "Upon exit, value=" << di.val << " and index=" << di.idx << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives for me:

```
~/tmp $ g++ -fopenmp myred.cc -o myred
~/tmp $ ./myred
Upon exit, value=6 and index=6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try "omp critical":

```
double max_calc_value = -DBL_MAX; // minimum double value
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 20; i < 1000; i++) 
{
    a_value = my_slow_function(large_double_vector_array, param1*i, .., param5+i);
#pragma omp critical
    {
        if (a_value > max_calc_value){
            max_calc_value = a_value;
            i_max = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is correct and will produce the expected results. But, please, don't use this in production code. Critical sections are not for free and when within the loop body, their overhead multiplies with the number of iterations. It is better to perform the reduction in two steps as shown in my answer or to use user-defined reduction operations in OpenMP 4.0+ as shown in Gilles' answer.